# what is missing in my sqlite syntax for foreign key?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, foreign-keys, constraints

I created two sqlite tables on android

`phone table` with primary key "id"

```
CREATE TABLE BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, KEY_PHONE TEXT UNIQUE,KEY_IS_BLOCKED BIT )
```

`comment table` with foreign key "id"

```
CREATE TABLE COMMENTS_TABLE ( id INTEGER, KEY_COMMENT_TEXT TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE(id))
```

why does the `comment table` don't refer `id` as a foreign key?

otherwise it won't have ids that are missing in the `phone` table.

how can I know my sqlite version?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps what you want is `FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE(id) ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: I never deleted any entry. so i don't think so

Comment: ahh but i use `long newRowId =
                db.insertWithOnConflict(BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE, KEY_ID,
                values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);`

Comment: to display version: SELECT sqlite_version()

Comment: but the `db.query()` syntax doesn't allow plain string as 1 and only arg

Comment: `db.rawQuery("SELECT sqlite_version()", null);`

Answer (score 0):

For backwards compatibility, foreign key checking is disabled by default.

You need to call [setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean)) in [onConfigure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29).